# convert RDD to Dataframe in 2.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert rdd to dataframe in Spark2.0

```
val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("dataframes").setMaster("local")
val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlCon=new SQLContext(sc)
import sqlCon.implicits._
val rdd=sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/alpha.dat").persist()
val row=rdd.first()
val data=rdd.filter { x => !x.contains(row) }

data.foreach { x => println(x) }


case class person(name:String,age:Int,city:String)
val rdd2=data.map { x => x.split(",") }
val rdd3=rdd2.map { x => person(x(0),x(1).toInt,x(2)) }
val df=rdd3.toDF()


df.printSchema();
df.registerTempTable("alpha")
val df1=sqlCon.sql("select * from alpha")
df1.foreach { x => println(x) }
```

but i a getting below error at toDF(). --->  "val df=rdd3.toDF() "

```
Multiple markers at this line:
- Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset. Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case 
 classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._ Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
- Implicit conversion found: rdd3 ⇒ rddToDatasetHolder(rdd3): (implicit evidence$4: 
 org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[person])org.apache.spark.sql.DatasetHolder[person]
```

How to convert the above to Dataframe using toDF()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a simple mistake where I had defined case class inside the main method. After removing the same, I am able to convert RDD to DataFrame.

```
package sparksql

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object asw {

case class Person(name:String,age:Int,city:String)
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val conf=new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Dataframe")
  val sc=new SparkContext(conf)
val spark=SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._


val rdd1=sc.textFile("/home/cloudera/alpha.dat")
val row=rdd1.first()
val data=rdd1.filter { x => !x.contains(row) }
val rdd2=data.map { x => x.split(",") }
val df=rdd2.map { x => Person(x(0),x(1).toInt,x(2)) }.toDF()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("rdd21")
spark.sql("select * from rdd21").show()

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloudera & Spark 2.0? hmmm, didn't think we supported that yet :)

Anyway, first of all you don't need to call `.persist()` on your RDD so you can remove that bit. Secondly, since `Person` is a case class you should capitalize its name.

Lastly, in Spark 2.0 you no longer call `import sqlContext.implicits._` to implicitly build a `DataFrame` schema, you now call `import spark.implicits._`. This is hinted at by your error message.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I am following https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-preview/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets  for  conversion of RDD to Dataframes        

import sqlContext.implicits._, we can use  in 2.0. Looks like the issue is with the Encoder

Comment: below dependencies i have provided in pom.xml
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: That's not the right version of documentation for the version you have. That's for 2.0.0-preview, and the implicit import changed between 2.0.0-preview and 2.0.0. See here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/sql-programming-guide.html